# Cruise control always sends email

Tags: .net, testing, continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net, cruisecontrol

I'm trying to set up CruiseControl.NET to notify developers whenever the build fails or is fixed but it sends emails after every build.

This is currently my publishers section of ccnet.config

```
<publishers>
  <email mailhost="smtp.gmail.com" from="***@gmail.com" includeDetails="true" mailhostPassword="###" mailhostUsername="***" mailport="587" useSSL="TRUE">
    <users>
      <user name="Developer" group="developers" address="%%%@hotmail.com" />
    </users>
    <groups>
      <group name="developers">
        <notifications>
          <NotificationType>change</NotificationType>
        </notifications>
      </group>
    </groups>
  </email>
</publishers>
```

I'm using CruiseControl.NET 1.6.

Thanks!
godwin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it turns out this was happening because I had my email as a user, but I was the 'modifier', so CC.NET wasn't sending me an email because I was in the developer group, but because I was the modifier.

I solved this by adding the 'modiferNotificationTypes' section to publishers:

```
<publishers>
  <email mailhost="smtp.gmail.com" from="***@gmail.com" includeDetails="true" mailhostPassword="###" mailhostUsername="***" mailport="587" useSSL="TRUE">
    <users>
      <user name="Godwin" group="developers" address="%%%@hotmail.com" />
    </users>
    <groups>
      <group name="developers">
        <notifications>
          <notificationType>Failed</notificationType>
          <notificationType>Fixed</notificationType>
        </notifications>
      </group>
    </groups>
    <modifierNotificationTypes>
      <NotificationType>Failed</NotificationType>
      <NotificationType>Fixed</NotificationType>
    </modifierNotificationTypes>
  </email>
</publishers>
```